# Restsharp : Unable to pass following parameters in post body

Tags: api, post, http-post, restsharp

I am trying to pass following parameters to request body but its not working :

```
{
  "Start": 0,
  "Limit": 10,
  "SysID": 632;
  "ResultScope": "Enrolled",

  "SearchParams":
  [
    {"Field":"ID", "Weight": 1, "Value": ["1234567"], "Operation": "Active", "Enabled": true}
  ]
}
```

What i tried:

```
var test = request.AddBody(new Search { Start = 0, Limit = 10, SysId = 632, ResultScope = "Enrolled", SearchParams = new List<Object> { "ID", 1, 1234567, "Active”, "true" } });
```

but its not working. I am getting target parametercount exception when i am trying to add it to request as Addobject after seralization

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read [the docs](https://restsharp.dev/usage/parameters.html#addjsonbody).

```
request.AddJsonBody(
    new Search { 
        Start = 0, 
        Limit = 10, 
        SysId = 632, 
        ResultScope = "Enrolled", 
        SearchParams = new List<Object> { "ID", 1, 1234567, "Active”, "true" } 
    });
var response = await client.GetAsync<WhateverYouWantBack>(request);
```